# unable to capture google search title from firefox addon

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, crossrider

I am developing a firefox addon by using crossrider which captures url and title. The addon works fine when trying to capture title and url from browser. The addon captures url fine from google search, but it captures the previous title and display it. The same code works fine in chrome. Please refer the code given below:

```
 var capture_data = {

       title : "not defined",
       desc: "not defined",
       url : "not defined",


       get_info : function(){

          this.url = document.location.href;
          this.title = document.title;
          console.log("Url: "+this.url+"   Title:"+this.title)

      }
 }


 window.onhashchange = function(){ 
    console.log(window.location.hash);
    capture_data.get_info();

 }
```

Please give me a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If onhaschange is triggering before page title is updated you can try a mutation observer to avoid setTimeout.

You will watch the `childNode` of `title` element.

So try this:

```
window.onhashchange = function() {
    console.log(window.location.hash);
    var title = document.querySelector('title');

    var mobs = new window.MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
        mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
            console.log(mutation.type, mutation);
            if (mutation.addedNodes && mutation.addedNodes.length > 0) {
                console.log('nodes added');

            }
        });
    });
    mobs.observe(title, {
        childList: true,
        subtree: true
    });

}
```

untested but should get you pretty far, just need watch the `console.log`s and you can narrow it down to do just what you need.

Comment: Thank you so much ,It is working great on firefox but not working in chrome.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know man I didn't test it so this is great news. The mutation observer implementation in other browsers may be a little different, Im not sure about how different though.

Answer (score 1):

I tested the provided code and could reproduce the issue you experienced.

It appears to be a simple matter of the *onhashchange* event handler being called before the page title is updated. The problem is resolved by introducing a short delay before getting the title, as shown in the following code.

```
window.onhashchange = function(){ 
  console.log(window.location.hash);
  setTimeout(function() {capture_data.get_info();}, 1000);
}
```

[**Disclosure**: I am a Crossrider employee]

Comment: Thanks you so much..,I had tried this before,Please let me know whether it fail in any cases since google search is very fast